# File type displays incorrectly in Windows Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, windows-explorer, pdf

I prefer to use google chrome as the default opener for pdf files. However, this causes Windows to display the type as "Chrome HTML Document" in File Explorer. Is there a way to make Windows accurately show the difference between .html and .pdf files while still having chrome be the default application, such as a registry edit or similar tweak?
Example:
[image: screenshot]

The first file is a .pdf and the last file is a .html, but they display the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible via registry edits, but you might create some issues
with the installation of future versions of Chrome
(Chrome updates do arrive frequently).

I outline below the schema for doing that, although I would really
recommend using a more evolved PDF viewer such as
[Foxit reader](https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/)
instead of Chrome.

You would need to go into the registry at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf`, where you will find that the
"(Default)" value is something containing the string `ChromeHTML`.

Pick up this string and go to
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML`. Export it to a `.reg` file;
use a text editor to change its name to for example `ChromePDF` and
its "(Default)" value to something like "Chrome PDF Document".
Then double-click the file to import it.

Return to the registry at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf`, and change in the
"(Default)" value the string `ChromeHTML` to `ChromePDF`.
This should complete it.

I recommend taking a backup by exporting any registry key that you
modify, before modifying. Create also a System Restore Point,
to be able to rollback your changes in the worst case.

Comment: Thanks. Since you said this might create issues with updating chrome, I don't think I will do it.  
An alterative another user suggested was to enable the File name extensions option under the View tab.